# Make FosUserBundle not to accept same password in change password dialog

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle to manage my users. Each user has to change password at least each 30 days. This is working - dialog shows and user can change password.

But unfortunately user can type in same password as before and FosUserBundle will accept it. How can I make FUB not to accept same passwords in change password dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify FOSUser User entity (extend user entity as usual and add an extra field with previous password field, or something like this) and logic beyond this (in controller or into "core")